# How do I add text to a video that looks like it belongs in the clip with Adobe Premier Pro CC?

Tags: video, editing

So I'm brand new to video editing and don't know were to begin. I filmed a piece of paper floating on top of water (the paper moves around in the frame) with the words "Survivor Tip #," on it. So I wanted to add text to the paper so I can use the same video just chance the tip number and make it look like the number could have been written on the paper before I filmed it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a new title (upper menu or rightclick in your project window) and define "Survivor Tip #" as text. Afterwards you can position and transform the text, so it looks like it is in your scene. Because your paper is floating you have to define different keyframes for your title-layer in the timeline, so the position changes accordingly to your floating paper.
Please check some tutorials in the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much normally I would look for tutorials but this time I wasn't even sure what to look for so you have been a great help.

Comment: You're welcome! :) (You can mark answers as correct with the tick on the left of it.)